# Check if there are Serial ports

Tags: c#, serial-port, serial-communication

I'm using this code to detect all available serial ports:

```
foreach (string PortName in System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames())
{
    PortBox.Items.Add(PortName);
}
```

Is there a way to `MessageBox.Show("Could not find any ports");` if there are no serial ports?

Comment: Do not use the SerialPort class if you haven't learned enough yet to know the answer to this question.  It will eat you alive and spit out your bones.

Comment: Well... I can only learn about it by asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GetPortNames()` returns an array.  Store this array as a variable and then check to see if it has `Length` zero.

```
string[] portNames = System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames();
if (portNames.Length == 0)
{
    // No serial ports - do whatever
}
```

Comment: You're welcome!  You can [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) my answer if you feel that it solved your problem.